# Standalone PyQGIS script is not working on Python virtual environment

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

Error while executing the script in Python virtual environment

```
(PVirtual) xor@HP-240:~/code/qgis$ python3 aa.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aa.py", line 2, in <module>
    from qgis.core import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'
```

working on terminal: if not using the Python virtual environment

```
xor@HP-240:~/code/qgis$ python3 aa.py 
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen factors.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
{'Pointmap': 0}
{'Pointmap': 5}
0 5
Point:  Pointmap Asset1 77.62277551171958 12.91716831378434
```

Since I'm using the MySQL and the Rest API also in the Python script so I need to use the Python virtual environment. but the QGIS code is not working in the Python virtual environment.